# customize Global Navigation (top link bar) without masterpage or publishing feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I would like to change Global Navigation so that all Site Collections within the Web Application will be visible, without changing or adding new masterpage, and publishing features are not enabled. thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamic navigation i.e. a new site collection added should automatically be available in the navigation menu then you will have to custom develop this 
http://www.sharepointmechanic.com/?p=439

Other options include jQuery:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-a-global-navigation-solution-across-site-collections.aspx

Or you can manually create links on the top navigation bar, but it would be tedious to maintain.

Comment: Thank you I have now created manually links on top Navigation bar. The site collection I created by powershell are host Named and have own content Database. When I browse to those site collections It generates error which says. System.Web.HttpException the siteMapProvider MyTestTopNavProvider cannot not be found.

Comment: Have you modified your web config file with custom Navigation provider? "My TestTopNavProvider" seems custom? if so, please check your web config entry and ensure the code has complied and deployed correctly.

Comment: thanks, Yes the web.config file has been modified correctly. it worked like a charm before I changed to Host-named site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make a point, the SharePoint Mechanic solution while useful does require a bit of administrative overhead and edits to the Masterpage. It also does not automatically add new site collections to the sitemap.xml file when they are created without some additional programming (not sure if you could use jquery or javascript or not). You would have to manually add the links to the site collection that has just been created in your sitemap.xml file.

Regarding the error message, the solution was not tested with host named site collections so I'm not sure if it will work with those or not. The error message you're seeing indicates to me that you are missing a reference to your MyTestTopNavProvider in your masterpage.